# sensortower daterangepicker greatly increasing load times

Tags: javascript, angular, knockout.js, daterangepicker

I am developing an angular 2 application and using [this](https://github.com/sensortower/daterangepicker) date range picker. Other pages load in 500 milliseconds. A page with this date range picker is taking more than 5 seconds to load sometimes more than 10 seconds. If I disable this date range picker its loading within 500 milliseconds.

In Typescript:

```
$("input").daterangepicker({
          minDate: moment().subtract(2, 'years'),
          ranges: {
              'Last 7 days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
              'Last 30 days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
              'Last 90 days': [moment().subtract(89, 'days'), moment()]
            },
            periods: ['day','month','quarter','year']
        }, function (startDate:any, endDate:any, period:any) {
          $(this).val(startDate.format('L') + ' – ' + endDate.format('L'))
          that.ts =  {

                'startDate' : startDate,
                'endDate' : endDate
            }

        });

<div class="form-group has-feedback" style="width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;">
      <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback" data-bind="
            daterangepicker: dateRange1,
            daterangepickerOptions: {
              single: true,
              standalone: true,
            }
          "/>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback" style="margin-top: 10px;"></span>
      </div>
```

Comment: `this date range picker` ?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added a link to https://github.com/sensortower/daterangepicker and changed the title to describe the problem better as well as improving the grammar and tensing of the question.

I would reccomend adding some code examples so we can see how you are loading the date picker.

Comment: @mplungjan  https://github.com/sensortower/daterangepicker